# running bower from TeamCity (Windows)

Tags: permissions, npm, teamcity, bower

I've got a set of build steps in a project (Team City 9.0c)

One of them is running `bower install` which is a simple command line execution with no parameters.

Bower is installed on the system (I can run it just fine from the command prompt on the machine) but I get the following error

`[10:47:35][Step 2/7] Starting: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script8385462966123630321.cmd
[10:47:35][Step 2/7] in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5d43cd6017ab83d4\website\Amaze.Web
[10:47:37][Step 2/7] 'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[10:47:37][Step 2/7] operable program or batch file.
[10:47:37][Step 2/7] Process exited with code 1
[10:47:37][Step 2/7] Step Bower (Command Line) failed`

I've seen this before where `PATH` is not set to the location of the npm binaries in `c:\users\xxxx\roaming\...` so the TC user cannot find them, however `PATH` is correct.

Both `npm` and `grunt` work successfully.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Is the path variable defined a user variable? If so, it should be a system variable which will be used by the TeamCity process.

Comment: No it's a system variable, which is what makes this most baffling.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written which accounts the build agent runs as.

I had a similar problem and my build agent was running using Local System. I had to create a dedicated windows user account for the teamcity build agent, in the build script I added

```
npm install -g bower 
set path=%path%;c:\path_to_bower_for_this_user;
```